# #define, #macro, #error refuse to function

Tags: basic, picaxe

I genuinely don't understand what's wrong with my code.

```
#ERROR "Code not finished!"
```

This claims a syntax error, despite [literally being in the manual](https://picaxe.com/basic-commands/directives/hash-error/).

[image: AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA]

I am expecting it to return "Error: Code not finished!" instead of "Error: syntax error".

There is no reason for this to not function. This also happens with any command directed at the compiler, such as #macro and #define. Again, taken [directly from the manual](https://picaxe.com/basic-commands/directives/hash-macro/).

[image: help]

What could I possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I didn't enable the preprocessor. I feel so dumb.

[image: omg]